# What is for .proxy() function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, proxy

What exactly `jQuery.proxy` function does in jQuery, and in which conditions this function is most useful?

I found [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) link, but I am not able to understand properly.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

Comment: To make sense of `jQuery.proxy()` I think you first need to understand how `this` works in JavaScript, so please read [MDN's article about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). jQuery's `proxy()` function is used to help you set `this` in certain circumstances.

Comment: @PaulS. - the OP already had a link to that page in his question...

Comment: Please be specific about what you don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) achieves the same thing as [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). Think of it like wrapping one function in another, i.e. a simplified example of it would be

```
function wrap(fn, newThis) {
    return function () {
        return fn.call(newThis);
    };
}
```

The purpose is so you can change the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) of a function and keep it static thereafter.

You can see the source of *jQuery's* implementation [**here**](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L461-L486).